# Adding a Condition to a LINQ join

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, linq

I'm working with the following linq query:

```
  var docList = from c in container.DocumentDeliveryPreferences 
                            join o in container.Documents on c.DocumentId equals o.DocumentId
                            select new { o.Name, o.DocumentType, c.CustomerId };
```

How can I modify this to select only Documents where c.CustomerId equals X(some paramenter)?

Comment: just add `where c.CustomerID == X` before `select` ??

Comment: What does this have to do with ASP.NET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something the following:

```
 var docList = from c in container.DocumentDeliveryPreferences 
               join o in container.Documents 
               on c.DocumentId equals o.DocumentId
               where c.CustomerId == X
               select new { o.Name, o.DocumentType, c.CustomerId };
```

where `X` is your parameter.

Comment: Thanks, this worked, I was putting the where in an incorrect place.